# Check if directory is being opened in Windows 10 explorer

Tags: batch-file, directory, explorer

I would like to detect whether or not a folder is "in use" (I am defining that as if it or any sub folder is opened in Windows File Explorer). Is there a way to get the paths of all folders File Explorers opened? I did some reading and some people say that explorer.exe is the process as the task bar/start menu and you have to change an option to separate it? I am fine with doing this as this program is only going to be on one PC.

I know batch isn't the best way to go about doing this, but **is this possible?**

Comment: why do you want to know that? If a folder is opened in an explorer window, that doesn't mean something is being done on that folder

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @phuclv I'd like to do something to that folder such as delete or move it somewhere after the user is done looking at it.

Comment: @DavidPostill I am not asking for code, at least that is not my intention, but rather if its possible, and possible what command or what would be the way to go about completing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. Even if you enable [*Launch folder windows in a separate process*](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-start-file-explorer-in-a-separate-process-in-windows-10/) then the new processes aren't called with the folder path in the command line

It may be possible if you attach a debugger to explorer.exe and read the path somewhere inside the process, but it's not a good way either, and will be very slow

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the type of answer I was looking for, just a bit bummed that it isn't really possible.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set AllWindows = objShell.Windows
For Each win in AllWindows
    WScript.Echo win.LocationUrl
Next
```

To use in batch

```vb
For /f "delims=" %A in ('cscript //nologo "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Bat+Vbs\ListOpenShellWindows.vbs"') Do @Echo %A
```

Comment: good that you have a solution. I know that it's possible to read the property somehow but I'm not proficient at VBS and COM objects. Note that it'll return blank for "This Computer" or libraries. So it won't show if one is opening Documents library for example. Anyway this should be the accepted answer

Comment: @phuclv See IWebBrowser2::get_LocationName (so in VB syntax it is just `.LocationName`)
 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752127(v%3dvs.85)