# Git Bash command in Windows to get the current path of the explorer

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I have recently moved from MacOS to Windows and new to bash scripts in Windows. I have install git bash for the bash shell. I am trying to write the
script to get the current path of explorer in the terminal.

How to get the current path of explorer using git bash?

Example:
Let's say we are opening `C:\Documents` and currently we are in `C:\Downloads` in terminal, I would want a function `cde` to cd to `C:\Documents` and if I open another folder in explorer the command cde will cd to that directory.

My attempt:

```sh
function cde() {
    current_explorer_path = xxx
    cd $current_explorer_path
}
```

Comment: What if you have multiple instances of `explorer` running ?

Comment: then the first opened explorer.

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55204235/2125671

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `explorer.exe` it is in 'C:\Windows`, so under **git bash** you should find it in` /C/Windows`.

Comment: I mean i would like to go to the any path that is open in explorer when i type "cde" in git bash terminal.